# Catch Ajax data variables in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the data used below to be caught in my alives.php page.
Essentially, alives.php requires a variable $passcode.

How do I pass the content of data below as the variable $passcode through a POST request?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#alive').click(function () {
      var data = '<?php  $row['code']; ?>';

      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        cache:false,
        url:"alives.php",
        data:data,    // multiple data sent using ajax
        success: function (html) {
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

**alives.php**

```
<?php 
require("database.php");

$checkvote = "SELECT code FROM votes WHERE code = '$passcode'";
$updatealive = "UPDATE votes SET alive = +1 WHERE code = '$passcode'";
$addvote = "INSERT INTO votes (code, alive) VALUES ('$passcode',+1 )";

$checkvoterlt = mysqli_query($con, $checkvote); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($checkvoterlt) > 0) {
   $result = mysqli_query($con, $updatealive) or die(mysqli_error());
} else {
     $result = mysqli_query($con, $addvote) or die(mysqli_error());
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Try using `POST` instead of `GET`, that'd be a good place to start...

Comment: Looks like [this has been covered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218399/ajax-get-requests-use-parameters-or-put-data-in-url).
Please also note that you're vulnerable to SQL injection because the `$passcode` variable is never sanitized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So much is wrong.

Problem 1: You are specifying a GET request: `$.ajax({ type:"GET",`. If you want it to be POST:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
```

Problem 2: Your javascript data variable should be `key: value` pairs like:

```
var data = { 'passcode' : code };
```

Then in PHP get the data with `$_POST['passcode']`

Comment: How does { 'passcode' : code }; get the content of $row['code'] or am I missing something?  I've changed my Ajax as above and am using $_POST['passcode'] on my alives.php page but it doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: `var data = { 'passcode' : <?php echo $row['code']; ?> };` then. I'm just not a fan of echoing PHP variables into javascript like that.

Answer (score 0):

This sort of passcode should NOT be passed to the client side, as it can be easily manipulated.

Instead, store such information in a `$_SESSION` variable (assumes you've started your PHP with `session_start`), as this will keep the value safe, pass it to all pageloads where it may be needed, and be impossible to manipulate (while it is possible to hijack someone else's session, a malicious user still won't be able to actively change the value)